# Ember-App-Kit: How to execute code only in release mode?

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit

I have created an error handler as described here:
http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/#toc_implement-a-code-ember-onerror-code-hook-to-log-all-errors-in-production

But this code is not only executed in production mode but also in normal debug builds which floods my server logs. I know that Ember.debug() calls and alike are being filtered out for production builds, but I couldn't find out where/how that is implemented and if that same mechanism could be used to make my code only fire in production code.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was not using the latest EAK.

Three days ago a [commit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/commit/ec861e3525b3c9151d89152fdca29e85bce04abb) was added that adds support at least in index.html.

You can do

```
<!-- @if dist=true -->
production code
<!-- @endif -->
```

now.